# Nokia HERE Maps: Letting user draw polygon on map

Tags: javascript, here-api

I want to create an option for users to draw polygons on maps,

Points should plot on clicking on map and when the first point is clicked again a semi-transparent polygon should be drawn.

How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 5):

You could add a click listener to the map that creates markers in the map.
the first marker you create should have a click listener to end the editing (remove the listener you first added to the map)
each time you create a new marker in the map you can draw the polygon.

```
//Supposing map is an instance of our map.
//Suposing we have a global instance of a container called myContainer and has been already added to the map
//suposing we have a global variable called polygon and has been already added to the map

map.addListener("click", addMarker);

function addMarker(evt){

  var pixelGeo =  map.pixelToGeo(evt.displayX, evt.displayY);
  var coordinate = new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(pixelGeo.latitude, pixelGeo.longitude);
  var marker = new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker(coordinate);

  //compare if it's the first created marker, so we can add an event listener for ending
  if(myContainer.objects.getLength() > 0){
      //add event listener to marker
      marker.addListener("click",finishPolygon);

  }

  //add marker to container
  myContainer.objects.add(marker);

  //paint polygon acording to markers
  paintPoly();
}

function paintPoly(){

   //grab coordinates from markers and draw polyline
   var aMarkers = myContainer.objects.asArray();
   var aCoords = [];
   for(var marker in aMarkers){
       var marker = aMarkers[marker];
       aCoords.push(marker.coordinate);
   }

   //remove polygon instance from map
   map.objects.remove(polygon);

   //add new polygon
   polygon = new nokia.maps.map.Polygon(
        aCoords,
        {
            pen: { strokeColor: #000, lineWidth: 1 },
            brush: { color: #ababab }
        }
   );
}
```

Hope this helps you as a guide.
you can check the object properties and functions in [Here maps](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.html)  developer page

Comment: Is there a way to check if there is already a event Listener attached to a function?